# Reading an Image dataset in java

Tags: java, hadoop

I am trying to read and write an image dataset in Hadoop using java. I am only convenient with the normal bufferImage.

```
folder = new File(""); 
img = ImageIO.read(f);
```

Answer (score 0):

`ImageIO.read` accepts an InputStream

You can get an InputStream from an HDFS file using the [FileSystem](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#open-org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path-) class's open function